# Proving regularity via equivalence classes

Tags: automata, regular-languages, finite-automata, proof-techniques

Given two regular languages $L_1$ and $L_2$, we define a new language

$$L=\{w_1w_2\mid \text{ there exist two words } x,y \text{ such that } xw_1\in L_1, w_2y\in L2\}$$

How do I show that $L$ is regular with equivalence classes?

My assignment allows the use of closure properties that all regular languages hold, but I cannot use $\text{rank} (L)$, as in show a limit to the number of equivalence class.

Can someone lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

If you are allowed to use closure properties (as the formulation in the question suggests) then $xw_1\in L_1$ so $w_1$ is a suffix of $L_1$, similarly $w_2$ is a prefix of $L_2$. Taking suffixes and prefixes is a closure property of regular languages, and so is concatenation. That solves the regularity.

At what level do you want/need equivalence classes for your answer?

(**added**) For language $K$ its set of prefixes is defined as 
$$\mbox{pref}(K) = \{ w \mid \mbox{there exists string $y$ such that } wy\in K  \}$$
precisely as used for $L_2$ in the operation in the question.

Given a finite state automaton for $K$ we get a FSA for $\mbox{pref}(K)$ by making all states final that have a path leading to a final state.

Also $\mbox{suff}(K) = \{ w \mid \mbox{there exists string $x$ such that } xw\in K  \}$.
Similarly one proves closure under suffix by making all states initial. As that is not commonly allowed for FSA that is solved by adding $\varepsilon$-transitions to all other states.

Your language $L$ based on $L_1,L_2$ equals $\mbox{suff}(L_1)\mbox{pref}(L_2)$, the concatenation of a suffix and a prefix language.

I could not find a reference to a question in this forum that dealt with the prefix/suffix operations, perhaps someone can help. Closure under prefix is a special case of closure under quotient.

Comment: "Taking suffixes and prefixes is a closure property of regular languages" can you elaborate on that? This was proven to us, or at least not in the way you are using it here.

Comment: OK, I tried to be more explicit. I am not certain whether these are the points you needed elaboration.

Comment: @HendrikJan : Hi Hendrik!..+1 to your answer, I request you please check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892394/automata-using-only-equivalence-class-to-proove-regularity/13931199#13931199) too

Comment: @HendrikJan What does mean by `rank(L)` here?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: ah, question also posted elsewhere! (where I do not have an account...). I believe rank(L) might be the number of equivalence classes for L. This number is finite iff the language is regular. That confuses me: according to the question we must use equivalence classes, but we cannot use the number of classes.

Comment: @HendrikJan : Thanks Hendrik .. I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

L =  {w1w2| there are two words, x,y such that : xw1 is in L1, w2y is in L2}  is regular if L<sub>1</sub> and L<sub>2</sub> are regular languages.

> L<sub>suff</sub>  = { w<sub>1</sub> | xw<sub>1</sub> ∈  L<sub>1</sub> }
>     L<sub>pref</sub>  = { w<sub>2</sub> | w<sub>2</sub>y ∈  L<sub>2</sub> }

**And,**

> L = L<sub>suff</sub>L<sub>pref</sub>

We can easily proof by construction Finite Automata for `L`.

Suppose Finite Automata(FA) for L<sub>1</sub> is  M<sub>1</sub> and FA for L<sub>2</sub> is M<sub>2</sub>.

**[SOLUTION]**
Non-Deterministic Finite Automata(NFA) for L can be drawn by introducing NULL-transition (^-edge) form every state in M<sub>1</sub> to every state in M<sub>2</sub>. then NFA can be converted into DFA.

e.g.
L<sub>1</sub> = {ab ,ac} and L<sub>2</sub> = {12, 13}

> L = {ab, ac, 12, 13, a12, a2, ab12, ab2, a13, a3, ab13, ab3, ............}
>   **Note:** w<sub>1</sub> and w<sub>2</sub>  can be NULL

M<sub>1</sub> =is consist of  Q = {q<sub>0</sub>,q<sub>1</sub>,q<sub>f</sub>}  with edges:

q<sub>0</sub> ---a----->q<sub>1</sub>,
 q<sub>1</sub> ---b/c--->q<sub>f</sub>

Similarly :

M<sub>2</sub> =is consist of  Q = {p<sub>0</sub>,p<sub>1</sub>,p<sub>f</sub>}  with edges:

p<sub>0</sub> ---1----->p<sub>1</sub>,
p<sub>1</sub> ---2/3--->p<sub>f</sub>

Now,  NFA for L called M will be consist of Q = {q<sub>0</sub>,q<sub>1</sub>,q<sub>f</sub>, p<sub>0</sub>,p<sub>1</sub>,p<sub>f</sub>} Where Final state of M is p<sub>f</sub> and edges are:

q<sub>0</sub> ---a----->q<sub>1</sub>,
 q<sub>1</sub> ---b/c--->q<sub>f</sub>,
 p<sub>0</sub> ---1----->p<sub>1</sub>,
 p<sub>1</sub> ---2/3--->p<sub>f</sub>,

q<sub>0</sub> ----^----> p<sub>0</sub>,
 q<sub>1</sub> ----^----> p<sub>0</sub>,
 q<sub>f</sub> ----^----> p<sub>0</sub>,

q<sub>0</sub> ----^----> p<sub>1</sub>,
 q<sub>1</sub> ----^----> p<sub>1</sub>,
 q<sub>f</sub> ----^----> p<sub>1</sub>,

q<sub>0</sub> ----^----> p<sub>f</sub>,
 q<sub>1</sub> ----^----> p<sub>f</sub>,
 q<sub>f</sub> ----^----> p<sub>f</sub>

^ means NULL-Transition.

Now, A NFA can easily convert into DFA.(I leave it for you)

**[ANSWER]**
DFA for L is possible hence L is Regular Language.

---

I will highly encourage you to draw DFA/NFA figures,  then concept will be clear.

Comment: How does this use equivalence classes?

Comment: @LukeMathieson : No it doesn't use equivalence classes..I myself confuse OP says don't use Rank(L) also says use equivalence classes. ..Although one can write solution using equivalence classes using L = L<sub>suff</sub>L<sub>pref</sub>  and summation